# Validate a Case has a Task before allowing it to be closed

Tags: apex, case, validation

Since rollup fields for Tasks aren't available I need an apex solution to count the number of related Tasks on a Case before allowing the Case to be closed.  This seems like it should be a fairly simple job but I have so little time to practice apex I need to relearn it every time a project calls for it.

I've created the following but I'm certain that it would hit query limits on a bulk update.  Could someone assist me with how to bulkify this?

```
trigger CaseBeforeUpdate on Case (before insert, before update) {
    Case[] cs = Trigger.new;
    // other methods called 
    // ... 

    // before allowing an Estimating Support case to be closed, insure that there is at least one TASK
    string eMsg = 'There must be at least one completed Task before you can close a Case'; 
    for (Case c2 : Trigger.new){
        if(c2.Status=='Closed' && c2.RecordTypeId == '01270000000Q9E1'){
            List<Task> tsk = [SELECT id FROM Task WHERE whatid =: c2.id LIMIT 1]; // only need 1 to pass
            if(tsk.size()<=0){ // less than 1 is a fail
                  c2.addError(eMsg); // raise error on page
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to go the DLRS route (which is an excellent option to purse BTW), here is a bulkified trigger that uises exactly one SOQL call and eliminates the hard coded recordtype Id

```
ID esRecTypeId =  Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Estimated Support').getRecordTypeId();
// Pass 1 - get interesting Cases
Set<ID> esCaseIdCloseSet  = new Set<ID>();
for (Case cs: Trigger.new)
   if (cs.status == 'Closed' && cs.recordTypeId == esRecTypeId)
      esCaseIdCloseSet.add(cs.id);  

// Pass 2 - get (using aggregate query) all task counts for these cases, grouped by Case Id
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = 
   [select whatid, count(id) taskCount
     from task 
     where whatId IN (select id 
                       from case 
                       where ID IN :esCaseIdCloseSet) 
     group by whatId];

map<ID,Integer> csIdToTaskCountMap = new map<ID,Integer> ();
for (AggregateResult ar: groupedResults)
    csIdToTaskCountMap.put(ar.get('whatId'),ar.get('taskCount'));

// Pass 3 - go through trigger and see if cases closing for Estimated Support RT have tasks

for (Case cs: Trigger.new)
  if (cs.status == 'Closed' && cs.recordTypeId == esRecTypeId &&
      !csIdToTaskCountMap.containsKey(cs.id)) // absence of entry means no Tasks 
     cs.addError('case can not be closed for this record type - no tasks');
```

You wouldn't have to use the aggregate query, you could also do:

```
[select id, (select id from Tasks) from Case where id IN : esCaseIdCloseSet]
```

and then test in a loop the value of `cs.Tasks.size() == 0` but aggregate queries are kind of cool and good to get to know.

Comment: I think OP wants to restrict user when the user attempts to close case but there is not even a single task related to it but I think your code is other way around, It does not allow user to close the case if there is a task related to it. Just wanted to mention that!

Comment: @javanoob -- ah -- good point -- I shall fix

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) by Andrew Fawcett to do your rollup. It should look something like:

[image: DLRS Config]

Once you have the rollup set up you can accomplish what you want with a simple `Validation Rule`, which would look something like:

```
AND(IsClosed, RecordType.DeveloperName = "My_RecordType", Task_Count__c = 0)
```